# How can I interact with Twitter using TweetSharp?

Tags: c#, twitter

According to [this page](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StarterProjects&referringTitle=Documentation), there are sample Apps that show how to use TweetSharp.
Said apps are to be in the "Demos" folder.  I'm not seeing them.

Q: Am I stupid?

Comment: there's also Twitterizer, which I've used with C#, and it works very nicely.

Comment: Does anyone here know @cf_PhillipSenn well enough to answer his actual question? :)

Comment: FYI: I have a WPF Twitter client using TweetSharp up on CodePlex. Check out http://halfwit.codeplex.com. Might be a useful sample app for you.

Comment: The answer might be argumentative.... ;)

Comment: Thanks Matt!  Your WPF example looks promising.  It's more than a Hello World though, so I quickly started drowning.  I'll post another question in order to see if someone can help me with Hello World.  I'm getting tripped up by OAuth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page states you need to check out the source tree. When you open the TweetSharp solution, there should be a Demos **solution folder** (not file system folder) containing the Demo.* projects. I haven't tried this myself, but that's what the TweetSharp.sln file is set up to do.

Comment: David is correct. It's a solution folder.  The Compact Framework code is in VS2008, everything else is in VS2010 (under src).

Answer (score 1):

Phillip:

The problem was you downloaded TweetSharp from the downloads tab.
You needed to download it from the Source Code tab instead, where it says "Latest Version", "Download".

Don't download from "Downloads", "Recommended Download".  I wouldn't recommend that.